# How do we get the unique IDs when returning data from the query

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GCP Datastore as a database. When I initialized the data I gave an image name as ID, still, it created a column Name/ID with unique Ids. But, when I try to return data by query it is only returning ID given by me. I need to get the auto-generated IDs also.

[image]

This is the code I'm using to query the entity.

```
var query = datastore.createQuery(['Defects']).filter('isProcessed', '=', false).filter('companyId', '=', id);

datastore.runQuery(query, (err, books) => callback(err, books, datastore.KEY));
```

Answer (score 1):

Datastore is a [NoSQL database](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview), and it uses unique ID's for each entity, which are automatically generated if not specified by you.

The problem is that you are returning `datastore.KEY`, which has the [following fields](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/Key):

```
Key {
  namespace: undefined,
  id: '1234567890',
  kind: 'My-Entity-Kind',
  path: [Getter] 
}
```

So reading the "id" field of the `datastore.KEY` object will give you the entity unique ID.

I did a quick example to show how to get the id in a similar example to yours:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = new Datastore();

var query = datastore.createQuery('My-Entity-Kind');

query.run((err, entities) => {
  const keys = entities.map((entity) => {
    var temp_entity = entity[datastore.KEY];

    // Save the id from the entity Key in a variable
    var entity_id = console.log(temp_entity["id"])

    // Print whole entity.KEY structure
    console.log(temp_entity)
    // Print only the entity id
    console.log(entity_id)
    // Print a random property
    console.log(entity["entity-property"]);

    return entity[datastore.KEY];
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think mapping through each object in the datatable would be time taking. I wish there is a better way to do this.

Comment: The `query.run` function returns an array of Entity objects as `entities`, and I can't think of a way to access each object property other than iterating through the list. You could maybe use `var keys = Object.values(entities)` to get all the array values, but you would have to iterate through the values anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
books[0][datastore.KEY]['id']
```

Comment: I could try this but my return type is an array. So, Do I have to map through each object in the array and add this to the object? I think this would be time taking if I have a large datatable.

Comment: 'Books' should be an array of 'Entity' objects